# How to prevent the browser from showing the default HTML validation error message

Tags: javascript, html, validation

How can I prevent the browser from showing the default HTML validation error message bubble?

```js
document.addEventListener('invalid', (function() {
  return function(e) {
    //prevent the browser from showing default error bubble / hint
    e.preventDefault();
    // optionally fire off some custom validation handler
    // myValidation();
  };
})(), true);
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the native html bubble or do you want to disiable html form validation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable client side validation for a form in HTML5 add a `novalidate` attribute to the form element. like this :

```
<form method="post" action="/mycation" novalidate>...</form>
```